# UITableView stops updating content while scrolling through view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nstimer

I have a UITableView with which works fine and updates fine. I also have a timer that updates each UITableView label and a progress view, when the user is scrolling the table view it stops updating/refreshing the content (labels and progress view) in the UITableView until they are done scrolling.

In addition to the content not updating I have found that when the user is scrolling the entire app hangs. I have two timers and I put print statement in both, but neither prints when the user is scrolling. I have not been able to find a swift or swift 2 solution to this.

Comment: Please, show us what you have done so far. The code related to how you did the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`  implementation would be especially useful for the community to help you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Xcode`. Please remove the `Xcode` tag from your question and read the tags before adding them.

Comment: My bad, Im a newbie

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is completely unrelated to Swift whatsoever.

You probably scheduled the `NSTimer` using the default method, which results in adding it to a runloop in a way that it's not triggered while scrolling. You need to add it to the main runloop with a `NSRunLoopCommonModes` mode instead.

E.g.

```
let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
NSRunloop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunloopCommonModes)
```

Comment: You are my hero! that first part made me laugh. This fixed the timing issue, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer as the solution, so I get more flair! ;)